# Deploy grunted submodule to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, gruntjs, compass

I have a project that has a Git submodule in the directory `server/shared`. The submodule is an AngularJS frontend (to be shared between multiple projects, hence the submodlue) that needs to be prepared with Grunt (internally also using Compass).

Right now, I `grunt` the project on my computer and deploy it to GitHub and Heroku. What I want instead, is to stop deploying Grunted files and instead deploy sources and have Heroku pull the submodule (which it does) and call `npm install` and `grunt deploy --target production` in `server/shared` (like I would on my local computer), which I cannot get to work properly.

I tried

- [`grunt-submodule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-submodule), which doesn't work because the project is not recognized as a Git project on Heroku (and I couldn't rebuild it to be seen as one);
- Many variants of "start `npm` and/or `grunt`" from either `package.json` or `Gruntfile.js` (in either the project root and/or `server/shared`), with the latter being made after [this example](https://gist.github.com/szimmers/7101729);
- Various NodeJS+Grunt+Compass buildpacks apart from Heroku's `heroku/nodejs`.

The main project is Flask (Python) and doesn't really need Node/Grunt/Compass/..., and it would be nice to keep it as clean from that stuff as possible (to make it easier to prepare other projects for this same deployment).

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it working, but I'm still open to better solutions.

I'll call the projects "Main" and "Frontend" (Git submodule of Main). Most of the setup was in Main, which I would still like to avoid, to make future similar installs simpler, but I don't know how to achieve that for now.

I added 3 buildpacks to Main: `heroku/ruby` (for Compass support; otherwise not needed), `heroku/nodejs` (for Grunt support), and `heroku/python` (because Main is a Flask project):

```bash
heroku buildpacks:clear &&
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby &&
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs &&
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
```

Then, I added `Gemfile` to Main:

```ruby
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'sass', "3.4.23"
gem 'compass', "1.0.3"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', "3.3.7"
```

The last line is not needed if you're not using `bootstrap-sass`.

You'll also need `Gemfile.lock`, which you can check/create/refresh with `bundle check`, `bundle install`, and `bundle update`.

We don't really need Grunt processing on Main, but we still need a `Gruntfile.js` in Main to invoke the processing of the submodule (created following [this example](https://gist.github.com/szimmers/7101729)):

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask('buildapp', function(dir) {
        var done = this.async();
        var done_or_error = function(err, result, code) {
            if (err == null) {
                grunt.log.writeln(result);
                grunt.log.writeln('processed ' + dir);
                done();
            }
            else {
                grunt.log.writeln('processing ' + dir + ' failed: ' + code);
                grunt.log.writeln('    ERR: ' + err);
                grunt.log.writeln('    RESULT: ' + result);
                done(false);
            }
        };

        grunt.log.writeln('processing ' + dir);

        grunt.util.spawn(
            {
                cmd: 'npm',
                args: ['install'],
                opts: {
                    cwd: dir,
                },
            },
            done_or_error
        );
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', function() {
        grunt.task.run(['buildapp:server/shared']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('heroku', ['build']);
};
```

If your Main is already using Grunt, you can add the above as one of the tasks in it.

To get this running automatically, create `package.json` in Main:

```js
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "compass": "^0.1.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-util-spawn": "0.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "grunt heroku"
  }
}
```

The key part here is `grunt heroku`. The rest is just my dependencies, which may be different for you.

The above will trigger `npm install` in Frontend. To have that one run Frontend's Grunt as well, add

```js
"postinstall": "grunt ..."
```

to `"scripts"` in Frontend's `package.json`. This is how you'd usually build your Frontend manually (in my case, the full command is `grunt deploy --target production`).

Don't forget to add generated files to `.gitignore`. For my Main, it's just `/node_modules`, while for my Frontend it is:

```
/node_modules
gen
/dist
/static/css
```

Ideally, you'll set your project to have only one directory with Grun-generated files (I have several, due to legacy reasons).